# Using a for loop to iterate through xml

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, for-loop, xml-parsing

I am trying to use a for loop to iterate through an XML document and place the data in the webpage. What I want this code to do is take the first 4 entries in the XML and display their title, date, time and description. The code I currently have looks like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","events.xml",false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
        var i = 0;
        for( i = 0; i <4; i++){

        document.write("<div style=\"display:block;padding-left:5px;\">");
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write("<strong>What:</strong> <span id=\"title\">  </span>");
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write("<strong>When:</strong> <span id=\"date\"></span> @ <span id=\"time\"></span>");
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write("<strong>Description:</strong> <span id=\"descr\"></span><br/></div>");

        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("date")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML =xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("time")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("descr").innerHTML =xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("descr")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}


    </script>
```

And the incorrect output looks like this.

```
What: Relay for Life Bingo
When: N/A @ N/A
Description: N/A

What: 
When: @ 
Description: 

What: 
When: @ 
Description: 

What: 
When: @ 
Description:
```

The first entry is not correct because it is the fourth element in the XML file and as you can see the rest is blank. I am new to XML so this is probably some beginners mistake but I would appreciate some feedback on how to get this to work.

events.xml

```
<event>
    <title>Relay for Life Wristband Sale</title>
    <date>March 26 &amp; 28 </date>
    <time>11 A.M - 3 P.M.</time>
    <descr>N/A</descr>
</event>

<event>
    <title>SHPE/SWE/EC/IEEE Dodgeball Event</title>
    <date>April 1 </date>
    <time>N/A</time>
    <descr>N/A</descr>
</event>

<event>
    <title>CH2MHILL Social/GBM</title>
    <date>April 2</date>
    <time>N/A</time>
    <descr>N/A</descr>
</event>

<event>
    <title>Relay for Life Bingo</title>
    <date>N/A</date>
    <time>N/A</time>
    <descr>N/A</descr>
</event>

<event>
    <title></title>
    <date></date>
    <time></time>
    <descr></descr>
</event>

<event>
    <title></title>
    <date></date>
    <time></time>
    <descr></descr>
</event>

<event>
    <title></title>
    <date></date>
    <time></time>
    <descr></descr>
</event>
```

Comment: please add events.xml also in this question

Comment: The Problem is the `id` of each tag, in your code you are replacing the first set of values while every time iterating the loop. You selecting the element with id's `title` `date` and so.They are same in all the element , They must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should be you events.xml with parent node events.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<events>
<event>
<title>Relay for Life Wristband Sale</title>
<date>March 26 &amp; 28 </date>
<time>11 A.M - 3 P.M.</time>
<descr>N/A</descr>
</event>
<event>
<title>SHPE/SWE/EC/IEEE Dodgeball Event</title>
<date>April 1 </date>
<time>N/A</time>
<descr>N/A</descr>
</event>
<event>
<title>CH2MHILL Social/GBM</title>
<date>April 2</date>
<time>N/A</time>
<descr>N/A</descr>
</event>
<event>
<title>Relay for Life Bingo</title>
<date>N/A</date>
<time>N/A</time>
<descr>N/A</descr>
</event>
<event>
<title></title>
<date></date>
<time></time>
<descr></descr>
</event>
<event>
<title></title>
<date></date>
<time></time>
<descr></descr>
</event>
<event>
<title></title>
<date></date>
<time></time>
<descr></descr>
</event>
</events>

Use Jquery, see the below code with your XML. It will easy for you.

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$.get('events.xml', function(d){

$(d).find('event').each(function(){
    var $entry = $(this);
    var title = $entry.find('title').text();
    alert(title);
})
}); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did have parent nodes in the original xml it just didn't copy correctly.

Comment: Are you still getting the issues with above code using jquery ??

Answer (score 0):

Check in **events.xml**, you have specified tags such title, date..

To parse XML use **XMLPullParser** in Android which is more effective and easy to use.

[How to use XMLPullParser](https://web.archive.org/web/20210117122522/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/05/how-to-use-xmlpullparser-in-android.html)